# Hover menu css chrome correct, ie and ff not

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

In chrome when hovering over a menu this happens (correct): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaexO.png

However in Ie and FF this happens: (i have removed some info on the page): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXLX8.png

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVeKC/

I cant see why is behaving like this in chrome and not IE and FF, recently chrome and FF have been behaving differently for me which is unusual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the left property for #nav li ul to be consistent in all browsers

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SVeKC/1/

Comment: Thank you :-) i just realised before your comment, however I will mark as right, thanks for helping :)